# inline intel syntax to inline gcc

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, intel-syntax

I'm trying to convert a snippet of mine to a compiler that uses an inline asm syntax similar to gcc's. I read the documentation and all was fine until I encountered this line:

```
mov eax, dword ptr fs:[0x20]
```

I converted that to:

```
movl 0x20(%fs:), %eax
```

The compiled flipped, telling me that fs is not a 32bit register and that this operation is invalid. How should I access fs in at&t syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it seems that gcc or the at&t is very inconsistent.

```
movl %fs:0x20, %eax
```